# Access to an inner type

Tags: c#, generics, types

A colleague of mine posted a question on an internal forum which got me thinking about whether this was possible through C#. Basically, he's got an interface as follows:

```
public interface IProvider<T>
{
    T GetT();
}
```

Is it possible to use something that implements that interface as a type parameter to another generic class and have access to the type T without re-specifying it? For example:

```
public class Foo<P> where P : IProvider<T>
{
    P p;

    T GetInnerT() { return p.GetT(); }
}
```

This does not compile, because the type T is not defined and hence can't be used as a parameter for `IProvider`. Is something like this even possible? Just curious!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, he'd need `Foo` to be generic in both P *and* T:

```
public class Foo<P, T> where P : IProvider<T>
```

otherwise there's no `T` for the `IProvider<T>` constraint to be aware of - the fact that it's part of the declaration of `IProvider<T>` is coincidental. The `T` in the above declaration is entirely separate (from the compiler's point of view) from the `T` in `IProvider<T>`. For example, this would be an equivalent declaration:

```
public class Foo<TProvider, TProvided> where TProvider : IProvider<TProvided>
```

Another thing to bear in mind is that an implementation of `IProvider<T>` could implement it multiple times, for different type arguments:

```
public class BigProvider : IProvider<string>, IProvider<int>, IProvider<char>
```

Now what would `Foo<BigProvider>` mean? It would be ambiguous... whereas with my declaration above, you'd do:

```
var x = new Foo<BigProvider, int>();
```

to mean the int-providing aspect of `BigProvider`.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible, because your definition doesn't allow for the provision of type `T` when declaring `Foo`.  Consider:

```
var x = new Foo<string>();
```

What is `T` in this case?  There is no way to know at compile-time nor at runtime.

As you yourself said: the type `T` is not defined, and for the class to be valid you have to provide a means of definition.  For example:

```
public class Foo<P, T> where P : IProvider<T>
```